# Searching for pages with any value in property

Tags: c#, .net, episerver

EPiServer only:

How do I search for pages with any value in a given property? I can do a search for pages with a specific value in the property, but I can't figure out how to search for "not empty".

For example, this doesn't work:

```
var criterias = newPropertyCriteriaCollection
{
  new PropertyCriteria()
  { 
    Condition = CompareCondition.NotEqual, 
    Name = "MyProperty", 
    IsNull = false, 
    Type = PropertyDataType.String, 
    Value = "" 
  }
};

var pages = DataFactory.Instance.FindPagesWithCriteria(PageReference.StartPage, criterias);
```

An exception is thrown, "The crieria value cannot be null or empty. Set the IsNull property to search for null."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this is confusing. In case anyone else stumbles on this, here's how to search for pages with a certain PageReference property set to something:

```
new PropertyCriteria()
{
    createdCriteria.Name = "MyProperty";
    createdCriteria.Type = PropertyDataType.PageReference;
    createdCriteria.Condition = EPiServer.Filters.CompareCondition.NotEqual;
    createdCriteria.Value = "0";
    createdCriteria.IsNull = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing a trick, this doesn't appear to be possible using the EPiServer PropertyCriteriaCollection.

I've had a dig around in reflector and here are my findings. The FPWC method eventually calls EPiServer.DataAccess.PropertySearchDB.FastFindPagesWithCriteria().

Within this method is the following:

```
    foreach (PropertyCriteria criteria in criterias)
    {
      if (criteria.IsNull)
      {
        criteria.Value = null;
      }
      else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.Value))
      {
        throw new EPiServerException("The crieria value cannot be null or empty. Set the IsNull property to search for null.");
      }
      ...
    }
```

So its not possible to search for an empty string value, without setting IsNull to true. This is then fed down to the EPiServer.DataAccess.PropertySearchDB.ExecuteCriteria method, which constructs and formats the DB command. Because IsNull is true, the netPropertySearchNull stored proc is used. Searching for a string needs to use the netPropertySearchString stored proc.

```
  if (criteria.IsNull && !PageDB.IsMetaData(criteria.Name))
  {
    cmd.CommandText = "netPropertySearchNull";
  }
```

My suggestion would be to load the full list of pages and filter using linq. Alternatively you could look into bypassing the API and implementing a direct DB query, or use some of the low level EPiServer data access methods (not recommended)

Apologies for my first answer - I really should test code before posting :)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something where the page has a a hidden bool property "Property X contains a value" that is set in the Saving event.

Then that bool property is used as a PropertyCriteria instead of the one you are REALLY interested in.

Answer (score 0):

## Solutions

### Solution 1: Refine PropertyCriteria

Use the following criterion:

```cs
var criteria = new PropertyCriteria
{
    Condition = CompareCondition.Contained,
    Name = propertyName,
    IsNull = false,
    Type = PropertyDataType.LongString,
    Value = "\0"
};
```

`\0` is the escape sequence for the NULL character.

### Solution 2: ContentLoader

One obvious solution would be to get all data via `ContentLoader` and compare values. But it's performance-heavy.

### Solution 3: Direct DB call

Yet another one would be to use direct SQL query in the code. It is significantly faster than above solutions.

```sql
SELECT content.pkid AS PkId,
       content.contentguid,
       cp.longstring
FROM   tblcontent content
       LEFT JOIN tblcontenttype ct
              ON content.fkcontenttypeid = ct.pkid
       LEFT JOIN tblcontentproperty cp
              ON content.pkid = cp.fkcontentid
       LEFT JOIN tblpropertydefinition tpd
              ON cp.fkpropertydefinitionid = tpd.pkid
WHERE  ct.base = 'Page'
       AND tpd.NAME = 'MyProperty'
```

Note:

You may switch from `cp.longstring` to the actual type.

You also may omit or substitute `base` with another type. Possible values:

- `NULL`
- Block
- Bundle
- Catalog
- Folder
- Node
- Package
- Page
- Product
- Promotion
- SalesCampaign
- Variation

Then, you may run the query in the Optimizely/Episerver like:

```cs
var executor = ServiceLocator.Current.GetRequiredService<IDatabaseExecutor>();

executor.Execute(() =>
{
    using var command = executor.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = sqlQuery;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    using var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default);
    using var dt = new DataTable();
    
    dt.Load(reader);
    var rows = dt.AsEnumerable();

    foreach (DataRow dataRow in rows)
    {
        // TODO: map like
        var id = dataRow.Field<int>("PkId");
    }
}
```

## Analysis

It seems it is not possible to do that in a simple way with the `DataFactory` or the `PageCriteriaQueryService` because of the following reasons:

- `PropertySearchDB`, which internally invokes stored procedures, does not support `NotEqual` compare condition:

```cs
switch (criteria.Condition)
{
  case CompareCondition.Equal:
    this.SetValue(cmd, "UseWildCardsBefore", (object) 0);
    this.SetValue(cmd, "UseWildCardsAfter", (object) 0);
    break;
  case CompareCondition.StartsWith:
    this.SetValue(cmd, "UseWildCardsBefore", (object) 0);
    this.SetValue(cmd, "UseWildCardsAfter", (object) 1);
    break;
  case CompareCondition.EndsWith:
    this.SetValue(cmd, "UseWildCardsBefore", (object) 1);
    this.SetValue(cmd, "UseWildCardsAfter", (object) 0);
    break;
  case CompareCondition.Contained:
    this.SetValue(cmd, "UseWildCardsBefore", (object) 1);
    this.SetValue(cmd, "UseWildCardsAfter", (object) 1);
    break;
  default:
    throw new EPiServerException("CompareCondition." + criteria.Condition.ToString() + " not supported in PropertySearch for strings.");
}
```

- The `PropertyCriteria.IsNull` works only if it is set to true; `ExecuteCriteria` code:

```cs
if (criteria.IsNull && !ContentDB.IsMetaData(criteria.Name))
{
  command.CommandText = "netPropertySearchNull";
}
else
...
```

Also, the `netPropertySearchNull` does not support non-null logic:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[netPropertySearchNull]
(
    @PageID         INT,
    @PropertyName   NVARCHAR(255),
    @LanguageBranch NCHAR(17) = NULL
)
```

So, to bypass the above logic, you may use the solution #1. Also, consider using direct DB call (#3) if performance is more critical.

Answer (score -2):

To find empty values you need to specify the [IsNull](http://sdk.episerver.com/library/cms5/html/P_EPiServer_PropertyCriteria_IsNull.htm)  property on the PropertyCriteria and use the Equal compare condition.

E.g

```
var criterias = newPropertyCriteriaCollection
{
  new PropertyCriteria()
  { 
    Condition = CompareCondition.NotEqual, 
    Name = "MyProperty", 
    IsNull = true, 
    Type = PropertyDataType.String
  }
};
```

Comment: I need the NON-empty values. The PropertyCriteria you suggested just gives me a collection of all the pages that doesn't have the property set - I need those with the value set.

Comment: I made a typo, The CompareCondition should have been NotEqual. I've corrected it. 

Update - that still doesn't work. Hmmm.